# Canvas issue on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jquery-plugins, touch-event

I am using a plugin for drawing inside canvas element.
It functions properly for desktops.
For mobiles there is a bug. I will try to describe it.
When you have for example 2 touchpoints (one after another but the switching happens immediately, with two fingers i mean) it functions incorrectly. It draws a straight line which connects the two touchpoints instead of simply drawing 2 separated points.
I tried different plugins but the issue exists in all of them.

Please, check this out with mobile if its possible and i think you will notice the bug i told above.

http://literallycanvas.com/index.html

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can check if count of touches > 1 (double touch or more ) just stop drawing something like this

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = (e.touches.length > 1) ? true : false;
    if (a) {
        drawing = false;
        return;
    }
    // draw your lines
});
```